# Initialize variable using Enum with duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Enum class with duplicate values. Each value in example represents register size in bits. I want to initialize variable by Enum name. Because they have same value, seems like Python takes first occurrence, ignoring Enum name I've passed.

```
from enum import Enum
class OperandType(Enum):
    EAX = 32
    EBX = 32
   
ebx = 'EBX'
new_op = OperandType[ebx]
print(new_op)
```

What will be printed here is:

```
OperandType.EAX
```

How to make it work as I expect?

Comment: Instead of an Enum, simply use a static constant class of values

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/enum.html#module-enum):

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to *unique*, constant values.

Thus, names that point to the same value will be treated as aliases of each other. Also see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values:

> Given two members A and B with the same value (and A defined first), B is an alias to A. By-value lookup of the value of A and B will return A. *By-name lookup of B will also return A.*

In your case, `EAX` was defined first and has the same value as `EBX`, so lookup of `EBX` gave you `EAX`.

As for how to make it work as you expect: not possible, because enums *don't* work like this.

Of course, you can create a mapping like this:

```
SIZES = {OperandType.EAX: 32, OperandType.EBX: 32}
```

...and then query the sizes via `SIZES[OperandType.EAX]`.

Comment: Correct. This behavior implemented in ____new____ function

Answer (score 0):

This will also work because class instances/enum values are unique:

```
class OperandSize:
    def __init__(self, size):
    self._operand_size = size

class OperandType(Enum):
    EAX = OperandSize(32)
    AAA = OperandSize(32)
```